# Sharepoint PersonOrGroup column with allowMultipleSelection allowed.how to pick LookUpValue from the API?

Tags: sharepoint, postman

This is the output of the API from postman call using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/ ,
when "**items?$top=5000&expand=fields"**,

Analyst is set as PeopleorGroup with multiple choise set to true.

"Test_x0020_Date": "2022-06-08T05:00:00Z",
"Manager": [
{
"LookupId": 1076,
"LookupValue": "ABC",
"Email": "ABC@def.com"
}
]

```
 How to customize this API to fetch only Lookupvalue from Analyst?  
expectation:
 "Test_x0020_Date": "2022-06-08T05:00:00Z",
  "Manager": ABC,
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following api

```
Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields    
Method: PATCH 
Body: {
  "{columnname}LookupId": "{userid}"
}
```